# How to get the concrete implementation of an interface by the generic type?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need some help figure out how to use reflection to get the concrete implementation based of the Dto type:

```
public interface IDocumentService<TDto>
{
}

public interface ICommentService: IDoumentService<CommentDto>
{
}

public abstract class DocumentService<TEntity,TDto>: IDocumentService<TDto> where TEntity: Entity, where TDto: Dto
{
}

public class CommentService: DocumentService<Comment,CommentDto>, ICommentService
{
}
```

So, what I want to do, is pass the CommentDto to a method so I can get to the CommentService.

```
public IDocumentService<TDto> GetDocumentService<TDto>()
{
    //based on the TDto type I want to find the concrete that 
    //implements IDocumentService<TDto>
}
```

I would call it like this:

```
var commentDocumentService = GetDocumentService<CommentDto>();
```

So, I would get back CommentService, knowing that I would only see the methods part of the IDocumentService interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation for GetDocumentService.

```
    public static IDocumentService<TDto> GetDocumentService<TDto>()
    {
        // Gets the type for IDocumentService
        Type tDto=typeof(IDocumentService<TDto>);
        Type tConcrete=null;
        foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()){
            // Find a type that implements tDto and is concrete.
            // Assumes that the type is found in the executing assembly.
            if(tDto.IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface){
                tConcrete=t;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Create an instance of the concrete type
        object o=Activator.CreateInstance(tConcrete);
        return (IDocumentService<TDto>)o;
    }
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted to return a new object, so I assumed so.

EDIT:

Due to your comment, here is a modified version of GetDocumentService.  The disadvantage is that you need to specify another type parameter.  The advantage, though, is that this approach provides a certain degree of type safety, since both type parameters must be compatible.

```
    public static T GetDocumentService<TDto, T>() where T : IDocumentService<TDto>
    {
        // Gets the type for IDocumentService
        Type tDto=typeof(T);
        Type tConcrete=null;
        foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()){
            // Find a type that implements tDto and is concrete.
            // Assumes that the type is found in the calling assembly.
            if(tDto.IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface){
                tConcrete=t;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Create an instance of the concrete type
        object o=Activator.CreateInstance(tConcrete);
        return (T)o;
    }
```

EDIT 2:

If I understand correctly, you want to get the other interfaces implemented by the type of the return value of GetDocumentService.  For example, `GetDocumentService<CommentDto>` returns an object of type `CommentService` that implements the `ICommentService` interface.  If I understand correctly, the return value should be a Type object (for example, the return value could be `typeof(ICommentService)`).  Once you have the type, you should call the type's `FullName` property to get the type's name.

Use the following method on the return value of `GetDocumentService` to get the type of interface implemented by that value, for instance, `typeof(ICommentService)`.

```
    public static Type GetDocumentServiceType<TDto>(IDocumentService<TDto> obj){
        Type tDto=typeof(IDocumentService<TDto>);
        foreach(Type iface in obj.GetType().GetInterfaces()){
            if(tDto.IsAssignableFrom(iface) && !iface.Equals(tDto)){
                return iface;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about testing this since I am using the GetCallingAssembly? If I had a Unit Test assembly that references my service assembly, how would I get to that?

Comment: Answer was edited.  Honestly I wasn't aware that `GetExecutingAssembly` was better here.

Comment: O, This worked perfectly and meant to mark yours as the answer. I got the GetExecutingAssembly() from Mohamed's answer and ran it in your code.  Can you see my comment in Mohamed Abed's answer about getting back the ICommentService interface instead?

Comment: O, Actaully, I want to return ICommentService because it implements IDocumentService<CommentDto>. I want it generic enough so that if I pass in another TDto type I will pull the correct interface. So, I could also have INoteService: IDocumentService<NoteDto>  If I were to pass NoteDto into the GetDocumentService<NoteDto> I would expect to get back INoteService. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  I will try to find the answer, but I will guess that that isn't possible due to the need to specify separate return types.  Something similar can be achieved with type constraints (`T GetDocumentService<TDto, T>() where T : IDocumentService<TDto>`) but that would require specifying an extra type parameter.  For now you will have to cast the return type manually as needed (for instance, to `ICommentService` or `INoteService`).

Comment: I was looking more for a way to return just the name of ICommentService and pass that into a Unity Resolver.  So, because we are looking for an IDocumentService<CommentDto> implementation, can't I just find the interface that implements that?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `CommentService` class needs to be discoverable somehow, given the type of `TDto`. You can search all the loaded types from all the assemblies in the current `AppDomain` - however that will be painfully slow.

So you have the following viable options:

- Use an attribute on the assembly that defines `CommentService`.
- Use configuration to define this information.
- Use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com).

I'll demonstrate the first approach. Firstly create the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class DtoProviderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ProvidedType { get; private set; }
    public Type ProviderType { get; private set; }

    public DtoProviderAttribute(Type providedType, Type providerType)
    {
        ProvidedType = providedType;
        ProviderType = providerType;
    }
}
```

And then apply it to the assembly that defines `CommentService` (typically you would put in `AssemblyInfo.cs`).

```
[assembly:DtoProvider(typeof(CommentDto), typeof(CommentService))]
```

Now you can use those attributes to search for the concrete implementations.

```
public class ServiceFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<RuntimeTypeHandle, Func<object>> _dtoMappings = new Dictionary<RuntimeTypeHandle, Func<object>>();

    public static IDocumentService<TDto> GetDocumentService<TDto>()
    {
        var rth = typeof(TDto).TypeHandle;
        Func<object> concreteFactory;
        lock (_dtoMappings)
        {
            if (_dtoMappings.TryGetValue(typeof(TDto).TypeHandle, out concreteFactory))
                return (IDocumentService<TDto>)concreteFactory();

            FillMappings();

            if (!_dtoMappings.TryGetValue(typeof(TDto).TypeHandle, out concreteFactory))
                throw new Exception("No concrete implementation found.");
            return (IDocumentService<TDto>)concreteFactory();
        }
    }

    private static void FillMappings()
    {
        // You would only need to change this method if you used the configuration-based approach.
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            var attrs = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DtoProviderAttribute), false);
            foreach (DtoProviderAttribute item in attrs)
            {
                if (!_dtoMappings.ContainsKey(item.ProvidedType.TypeHandle))
                {
                    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.New(item.ProviderType), typeof(object)));
                    _dtoMappings.Add(item.ProvidedType.TypeHandle, expr.Compile());
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

As 'Rune' pointed out: because of the cache the overhead of searching all the assemblies is low:

```
    private static void FillMappings()
    {
        foreach (var type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract))
        {
            foreach (var iface in type.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDocumentService<>)))
            {
                var arg = iface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                if (!_dtoMappings.ContainsKey(arg.TypeHandle))
                {
                    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.New(type), typeof(object)));
                    _dtoMappings.Add(arg.TypeHandle, expr.Compile());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be slow to search through all types. First time you do it uild a map. Use the Dto type as key and service as the value. Every following lookup is O(1) (and it's a rather low constant too)

Comment: @Rune thanks - guess I am a bit dumb today. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

another possibility:

```
public IDocumentService<TDto> GetDocumentService<TDto>()
        {
            var genericParameter = typeof(TDto);

            return (from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()     // Get Types
                    where type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null          // That is concrete
                    let interfaces = type.GetInterfaces()                       
                        from intf in interfaces
                    where intf.IsGenericType                                    // Which implement generic interface
                        let genarg = intf.GetGenericArguments()[0] 
                            where genarg == genericParameter                    // Where generic argument is of type genericParameter
                            select (IDocumentService<TDto>)                     // Cast to IDocumentService
                            Activator.CreateInstance(type)).FirstOrDefault();   // Instantiate
        }
```

Comment: Do you know how I would get the name of ICommentService based on the TDo value? If I were using Unity to instantiate my object how would I pull just the interface name?

Comment: I apologize for unmarking this as the answer. I actually was running Peter O's code, but got the idea for the GetExecutionAssembly method from you. your code always returns null for me.